# EFI boot error: please append a correct device "root=" boot option

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi

I try to start the system without a boot loader for faster boot.
I compiled the **Linux-kernel-5.8.5** and copied the `.../arch/x86/boot/bzImage` file to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu.efi`. Reboot in to BIOS, selected **ubuntu.efi** and added to the **secure boot**.
The system starts but I get the following error:

```
Please append a correct device "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
(driver?)
103:00001 123456 nvme0n1p1 ...UUID....
103:00002 123456 nvme0n1p2 ...UUID....
103:00003 123456 nvme0n1p3 ...UUID....

kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

The **pci**, **fs** and **nvme** driver are build in the kernel (*).

Comment: You haven't provided OS/release details, however that kernel currently is only used by an off-topic (*development*) release of Ubuntu

Comment: OS: ubuntu 20.04, Linux-kernel from: kernel.org

Comment: I'm using the Ubuntu 5.8 kernel, however my release is off-topic (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and you've not yet provided details as to your OS/release and thus if you're off-topic too.  Did you add `ubuntu-sauce` to your kernel?

Comment: No, didn't add any patches, clean upstream kernel. I will try `ubuntu-sauce`. As far as I can tell, only the path to the partition and the `root` directory have to be entered: ` UUID / root`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after fresh install Xubuntu 22.04 on HP EliteDesk 705 G4 DM with m2.NVMe drive. While booting I got:

```
VFS: Cannot open root device nve0n1p2 or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
Please append a correct "root" boot option; here are the available partitions:
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

There were no available partitions in my case.
As turned out it was necessary to update initramfs.

I booted to live Xubuntu again and used chroot.
Prerequisites what to know:

- disk name, for example **sda**, in my case **nvme0n1p** (can be seen for example in Gparted)
- EFI partition number, usually **1**,
- Linux partition number, in my case **2**,
- type of filesystem in the Linux partition, in my case **ext4**

Commands to run in a terminal, can be copied to a text editor, changed according to prerequisites and than pasted in the terminal window:

```
d=nvme0n1p # Disk with installed Linux
e=1   # Number of EFI partition
p=2   # Number of partition with installed Linux
sudo mount -o X-mount.mkdir -t ext4 /dev/${d}${p} /mnt/linux
sudo mount /dev/${d}${e} /mnt/linux/boot/efi
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/linux/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/linux/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/linux/proc
sudo mount --rbind /sys /mnt/linux/sys
sudo chroot /mnt/linux
```

In changerooted system I got kernel version by command:

```
uname -r
```

and received **6.2.0-26-generic** so I updated initramfs and grub:

```
update-initramfs -u -k 6.2.0-26-generic
update-grub
```

and exited from chroot:

```
exit
```

Next boot was successful.